# Normalizing CSV file data

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssis, normalization

So I have a CSV file that is formatted like this:

ReturnID|Employee|CreateDate|ProductID|Quantity
100|EMP1|2014-09-15|20|500
100|EMP1|2014-09-15|21|30

The ReturnID identifies the return and ProductID identifies the product(s) that are associated with a return.

I need to normalize the data from the CSV file and import the data in this form:

A single return record that contains the fields:
ReturnID|Employee
100|Emp1

and

Two Product records that are associated to the return record. 
These two records would look something like this:

ReturnID|ProductID|Quantity
100|20|500
100|21|30

I'm planning using SSIS to import the CSV file, but I would like to do the normalization using SQL Server.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: so your requirement has nothing to do with CSV?

Comment: We receive a CSV file that needs to be imported into the database in the manner I described.

Comment: Why not import to a import table and normalize from this table via script?

Comment: That would be fine as well, I'm just unsure of the SQL that would allow me to do this.

Comment: do you want to do transformation within SSIS data flow or after it gets to database? in any case it has nothing to do with CSV really

Comment: The process could be: import the CSV file into an import table, transform it with SQL, and insert the transformed records into the database. I know it has nothing to do with CSV, I was just trying to illustrate the situation as complete as possible in case there were better solutions available. I would like to use SQL to perform the transformation though.

Comment: That is not difficult to do this directly in SSIS data flow, but impossible to demonstrate on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not impossible to demonstrate on SO. ;)

[image]

There's nothing intrinsically special about the source data being a CSV. You just have the data. I will simulate it with a source query and add an additional return to ensure I have the problem solved for N returns.

You're looking at a Multicast operator. This allows you to perform operations on the same set of data so we will have N streams of data coming out of it. This doesn't duplicate the data, simply allows different operators to work on it.

We will have two streams here. One for aggregation (to generate the unique combination of ReturnID and Employee) and one for the detail data (ReturnID, ProductID and Quantity).

I use an Aggregation transformation on the data and use the GroupBy operation for `ReturnID` and `Employee`.

I assume the detail data is already at the correct level of granularity but if it could be further summarized, add an Aggregate operation in there, GroupBy the ReturnID and ProductID and SUM the Quantity.

### Biml

Biml, the Business Intelligence Markup Language, describes the platform for business intelligence. Here, we're going to use it to describe the ETL. [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com), is a free add on for Visual Studio/BIDS/SSDT that addresses a host of shortcomings with it. Specifically, we're going to use the ability to transform a Biml file describing ETL into an SSIS package. This has the added benefit of providing you a mechanism for being able to generate exactly the solution I'm describing versus clicking through many tedious dialogue boxes.

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <!-- 74383 -->
    <Connections>
        <OleDbConnection ConnectionString="Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=localhost\dev2014;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=tempdb" Name="CM_OLE" />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="so_25855263" ConstraintMode="Linear">
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="DFT Make Data">
                    <Transformations>
                        <OleDbSource ConnectionName="CM_OLE" Name="OLE_SRC Gen data">
                            <DirectInput>SELECT
    D.*
FROM
(
    VALUES
        (100,'EMP1','2014-09-15',20,500)
    ,   (100,'EMP1','2014-09-15',21,30)
    ,   (200,'EMP2','2014-09-25',20,10)
    ,   (200,'EMP2','2014-09-25',21,20)
    ,   (200,'EMP2','2014-09-25',22,30)
    ,   (200,'EMP2','2014-09-25',23,40)
) D(ReturnID,Employee,CreateDate,ProductID,Quantity);</DirectInput>
                        </OleDbSource>
                        <!--
                        Multicast our data
                        -->
                        <Multicast Name="MC Create alternate paths">
                            <OutputPaths>
                                <OutputPath Name="AggregatePath">
                                </OutputPath>
                                <OutputPath Name="Default">
                                </OutputPath>
                            </OutputPaths>
                        </Multicast>

                        <!--
                        Handle aggregating the data based on ReturnID and Employee
                        -->
                        <Aggregate Name="AGG ReturnID and Employee" >
                            <InputPath OutputPathName="MC Create alternate paths.AggregatePath" />
                            <OutputPaths>
                                <OutputPath Name="AGG Out">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <Column SourceColumn="ReturnID" TargetColumn="ReturnID" Operation="GroupBy"/>
                                        <Column SourceColumn="Employee" TargetColumn="Employee" Operation="GroupBy"/>
                                    </Columns>
                                </OutputPath>
                            </OutputPaths>
                        </Aggregate>
                        <!--
                        Do something with the aggregated data. 
                        -->
                        <DerivedColumns Name="DER bitbucket Aggregate">
                            <InputPath OutputPathName="AGG ReturnID and Employee.AGG Out"/>
                        </DerivedColumns>
                        <!--
                        Do something with the other "half" of the data
                        I assume it is already aggregated at the ReturnID|ProductID|Quantity level.
                        If this is incorrect, patch in another aggregate
                        -->
                        <DerivedColumns Name="DER bitbucket default">
                            <InputPath OutputPathName="MC Create alternate paths.Default" />
                        </DerivedColumns>
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume that you managed to get your data to 'MyImport' table.

All you need to do is use DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ReturnID, Employee FROM MyImport;
SELECT DISTINCT ReturnID, ProductID, Quantity FROM MyImport;
```